# how to add two js variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is my code...

```
function calculateAmount(plotSize,planRate){

var amount = plotSize*planRate;
var currenamount= ('#totalamount').val();
 if(currenamount=='Amount'){
currenamount=0;
}
var c = parseInt(amount) + parseInt(currenamount);
$('#totalamount').val(c);

}
```

I want to add varriable currenamount and amount and display it in the totalamount div.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: WHY have you tagged this as codeigniter?

Comment: ('#totalamount').val(); you have missed $, this should be $('#totalamount').val();

Comment: Are you sure its currenamount=='Amount' and not currenamount==amount , because currenamount seems to be a numerical value and you are equating it with a string 'Amount'.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `$` beofre the `(#totalamount)` so  Current amount should be initialized like:

```
var currenamount= $('#totalamount').val();
                 ^^^ $ here
```

As described in a comment that if `totalamount` is a div then you can  try this

```
var currenamount= ('#totalamount').text();
```

And  to set text as a total amount to div:

```
$('#totalamount').text(c);
```

Comment: may be `Amount` is the value from `input`

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti May be but nothing is clear in the question so far :)

Comment: amount is just a text in totalamount div